# Инъекция объекта Request НЕ в контроллер

Tags: php, ооп, laravel, шаблоны-проектирования

Хотел бы получить совет насчет инъекции объекта `Request` (и других классов которые работают с внешними данными), в сущности которые не являются контроллерами.

Например, у меня есть класс `PaginationViewer` который отвечает за рендринг пагинации:

```
class PaginationViewer
{
    public function __construct(DbPaginator $paginator, Request $request)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        ...
        $paginateViewer = new PaginationViewer($dbPaginator, $request);

        return View::create('index.blade.php', [
            'paginateView' => $paginateViewer->render(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Задача `DbPaginator` в данном случаи - предоставлять информацию о количестве страниц, интервале и т.д. (это наверное и не важно).
От объекта `Request` мне нужны параметры из get запроса.
Насколько хорошей практикой считается передавать весь `Request`не в контроллер?
В принципе я могу обойтись и одним массивом, но в последнее время у меня появилось убеждение, что код на массивах сложнее поддерживать.

Comment: А зачем весь запрос там нужен? По идее фильтрация и трансформация данных запроса делается в вспомогательных классах где происходит маппинг и очистка от возможных осложнений, и уже они используются дальше.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Из request мне нужно имя роута  и get параметры для генерации ссылок на страницы пагенатора.  Да, я тоже думал о вспомогательном классе, но тогда все равно придется передовать Request в вспомогательный класс. Если трансформацию делать в контроллере, до будет дублирование кода

Comment: Получается так, что ваш PaginationViewer теперь зависит от объекта Request. т.е. любое изменение объекта повлечет перепроверку этих зависимых классов. По мне так это плохая практика. Мое мнение такое: если 2 класса не являются частью решения ОДНОЙ задачи (простыми словами: если у каждого класса свое назначение и он не является вспомогательным для другого класса изначально) то они должны быть независимы друг от друга.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше передавать объект конечно же как по мне, плюсы:

1. Обьект передается по ссылке, хотя массив тоже можно передавать по ссылке, но не суть.
2. Typehint, если php7+ то проще будет следить за всем чтобы не сломалось что либо.
3. Не факт что в будущем вам не понадобятся значения с куков или сессии или POST, у вас это уже всё будет.
4. Главный фактор как по мне, с обьектом проще работать чем с массивом, сейчас многие в PHP придерживаются практики чтобы в массивах данные не передавать, т.к. сложнее работать с ними, сам так практикую последний год и скажу что так действительно удобнее, с версии PHP7+ может и раньше уже не проблема пара лишних обьектов.

Так что я бы советовал передавать Request и не переживать.

Comment: Четвертый пункт по мне так очень ошибочный. Возьмите любой фреймворк, из коробки процент функций который работает с массивами в разы больше чем с объектами. Хотя конечно все зависит от задачи и преследуемого результата.

Comment: @Manitikyl фреймворк ориентирован на широкий круг людей и как я думаю на низкий порог вхождения, да и всё от методологии зависит и от требований к продукту, я бы не брал фреймворк как правило